# Error in mclapply(1:20, function(ii) { : Windows does not supprot 'mc.cores' > 1

Tags: r

I try to reproduce and run the code from GitHub: https://github.com/sangwon-hyun/omd. I first try to run the code from the file: 01-climatology.Rmd (https://github.com/sangwon-hyun/omd/blob/master/main/01-climatology.Rmd)

When I run the code after the 296th line "Toy distances" part.

```
library(parallel)
```

```
start.time = Sys.time()
dists = mclapply(1:20, function(ii){
  printprogress(ii, 20, start.time = start.time)

  dat1 = darwindat %>% add_blob(c(-150, -25))
  dat2 = darwindat %>% add_blob(c(-150 + 2*ii, -25), rotate = (ii / 20) * 90)

  val1 = dat1 %>% pull(val)
  val2 = dat2 %>% pull(val)

  costm = form_cost_matrix(dat1)
  res = omd(M1_long = dat1,
            M2_long = dat2,
            p = 1,
            ## costm = costm,
            geodesic = TRUE)

  diffval = val1 - val2
  twodists = c(omd = res$dist, rmse = sqrt(sum((diffval)^2)))

  return(twodists)
}, mc.cores = 3)

distmat = do.call(rbind, dists) %>% as_tibble()  %>%
  tibble::add_column(shift = 2*(1:20)) %>%
  mutate(omd = omd-min(omd), rmse = rmse-min(rmse)) %>% 
  mutate(omd = omd/max(omd), rmse = rmse/max(rmse)) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c('omd', 'rmse')) 

saveRDS(distmat, file = file.path(datadir, "distmat-toy.RDS"))
```

It reports the error:

```
Error in mclapply(1:20, function(ii) { : Windows does not supprot 'mc.cores' > 1
```

I use R 4.2.0. How to fix this error?

Comment: You can use `parLapply` instead (but there is also a bit more book-keeping to do to move data and functions to each node)

Comment: or just use `future_lapply()` it can be used like the regular `lapply`-function, you just need to use `plan(strategy = multisession)` to enable multi core procesing before your `future_lapply` call, as well as returning to sequential computing afterwards with `plan(strategy = sequential)`

Comment: @D.J But it shows that '  could not find function "future_lapply'?

Comment: @user20650 It shows that `Error in checkCluster(cl)"?

Comment: @D.J Can you please explain more? Thank you!